# Visual Studio - Git - Lots of Branches

Tags: git, visual-studio, asp.net-core, github

Am stumbling my way through the use of Git in Visual Studio.

1. Create Branch from Master with name of new feature
2. Code up and test the branch
3. Check out master
4. Right-click on branch and select "merge into master"

seems to be a basic workflow.

My question is that as the number of branches grows then when I check out the master (step 3) ready for step 4, I lose any visual clues as the branch I wish to merge and it seems far too easy to select the wrong branch to merge.  They're in alphabetical order rather than chronological, so I need to make a note of the branch that I'm going to merge into the checked out master.

It may not be rocket science to "not forget" which branch I'm merging, but I'm wondering if I'm missing a trick of the trade and there's a more optimal way of using the VS Git UI when merging an existing branch back into the master?

Comment: If you merged a branch and the feature is complete, it is fine to delete the branch — it serves no further purpose.

Comment: But, of course!!  The master has the full trail.  Duh!  Thanks.